# Browser render safety fonts instead local

Tags: html, css, fonts

When i open devtools in chrome or firefox,  find my .page-header__hero-motivation and see render font is Comic Sans, not Caveat.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Caveat";
  src: url("../fonts/Caveat-Regular.woff2") format(woff2),
    url("../fonts/Caveat-Regular.woff") format(woff);
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}

.page-header__hero-motivation {
  font-family: "Caveat", "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #8E80A9;
}

My website tree

index.html
css -> style.css
fonts -> Caveat-Regular.woff2 & Caveat-Regular.woff
```

take this font from googlefonts and convert in online to woff&woff2.

[chrome devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqj6k.png)

Comment: My project https://send.firefox.com/download/989e94eb79ecddd6/#LbboKPOpnqTzciMOE67D0g

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Comic Sans is the generic family not the font family. Don't set both, just set either font or generic family, also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family
Tell me if it works, otherwise post the entire code please.

Comment: If i delete comic, chrome render Times. I set two fonts for fallback. https://css-tricks.com/css-basics-fallback-font-stacks-robust-web-typography/

Comment: then your browser can't find the fonts. How did you implement them in your environment? Did you set the right path?

Comment: If i put /css/../fonts/Caveat-Regular.woff2 in path - i can download this font.

Comment: did you try to use Caveat regular? This is the font you have saved locally, but you do not refer to that.

Comment: Font-family: Specifies a name that will be used as the font face value for font properties. If i write "MegaFont" in @font-face and in my class font-family - its work. File name, font-family and font name don't binding.

Answer (score 0):

OMG, i kill about 5 hours on that...

I forgot quotes in format @font-face

**wrong**

```
format(woff2)
```

**right**

```
format("woff2")
```